# How to exclusively lock a row that prevent CRUD operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Hi expert
how I can lock a row in sql server that prevent CRUD operation even SELECT.
Is it Possible?
Serializable Isolation level does not prevent SELECT.
thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN

    SELECT 1
    FROM Table
    WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)

COMMIT TRAN
```

That will do the trick.

**EDIT**

*As noted by others, you cannot lock a row to not be read*. The only way I know of doing this is as follows:

```
WITH (UPDLOCK, TABLOCK)
```

And this is assuming that a WITH (NOLOCK) is never used in a SELECT statement (which should be avoided anyway).

I tested this and it will work, although TABLOCK should only be used in extreme cases. Certainly if concurrency is required, it's a bad solution and some other form of locking would be needed. One way is to update a bit column "Available True/False" and only read rows where Available = True. As @gbn suggested, READPAST *could* be used with this.

Comment: I just tested this, and XLOCK works as good as UPDLOCK for selects.  also see: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2006/12/13/does-xlock-always-prevent-reads-by-others.aspx

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I rightly or wrongly believe the OP is looking for an exclusive lock because they said they want to "prevent CRUD". I don't know if this is only against updates, or includes locking rows that have been read. So I opted for exclusive lock. If it isn't against rows that have been read, then 100% I'd use UPDLOCK.

Comment: Probably because the real answer is "No, it's not possible".

Comment: I don't think @gbn confirms your answer will prevent selects. in fact your code **will not** prevent a `select`.  try it out, open two windows in SSMS and run your (without the `commit tran`) in window 1.  then run a select on the row in question in window 2, are any rows returned? yes.

Comment: @KM I tried it & you are correct. Wow, so much for the meaning of the word "exclusive". I have edited my answer & comments accordingly.

Comment: @KM I am always certain about what I believe, but not stubborn so that I cannot change what I believe when shown better. At least I listened, learned, and corrected the error.

Answer (score 5):

try using the `ROWLOCK` and `UPDLOCK` inside a transaction something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @ID = ID
FROM YourTable WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK)
WHERE ....

--more--

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

however you can't prevent a SELECT that uses the NOLOCK hint from "dirty" reading this.

Comment: @ IanC, the title of the question is **How to exclusively lock a row that prevent CRUD operation**

Comment: @KM I know. "How to *exclusively lock*" = XLOCK. :-)

Comment: lanC, the XLOCK hint does not prevent dirty reads.  The best it will do is prevent inserts, updates and deletes but not selects.

Comment: @Chris you are correct. From what I have subsequently read on this, it seems XLOCK is to be avoided, and rather UPDLOCK should be used, as you state.

Answer (score 2):

As well as ROWLOCK, XLOCK as suggested by other folk, I would consider READPAST in addition

This allows allows other readers and writers to *skip* the lock on this row. This can increase concurrency because the lock set by ROWLOCK, XLOCK s blocking otherwise

Comment: Good point, although the OP should note that this skip means skipping the locked rows entirely, as in they won't appear in the results, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: I quite like the idea of READPAST because it will allow the developer the ability to handle the possibility of not finding the row and therefore continuing on without deadlock occurring.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server already natively locks a record from dirty reads as it is being updated.  This has the effect of blocking the select call until the update / insert call is complete.

Comment: Although the statement is true, using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED (or specifying NOLOCK) will still return dirty reads.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to lock a row using a locking hint WITH (ROWLOCK), however a SELECT statement can always get around it by adding a locking hint WITH (NOLOCK) which will provide a dirty read.

Comment: This is not true. WITH XLOCK, ROWLOCK will guarantee a read lock on a row. Out of interest, NOLOCK is being deprecated.

Comment: Actually, it is true. My example uses ROWLOCK, not XLOCK. However a simple test will prove that a NOLOCK will still return rows against a table with an exclusive lock on it. 

begin tran
select * from table with (xlock, rowlock)
where primarykeyid = 1

Using another connection:
select * from table with (nolock) where primarykeyid = 1

The second select statement still returns rows even though an exclusive lock exists on the selected row.

Comment: I tested this and you are correct. It seems the "X" exclusive designation is both meaningless and misleading. I have corrected my comments and answer accordingly.