# Record locking not working properly

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013, record-locking

I am using access 2013 on the front end and sql server 2014 on the backend. I have a form in access that has Record Locks set to "Edited Record" and under Options`->`Client Settings`->`Default Record Locking I have "Edited Record" checked.

I want the record to lock on the form when one user is editing the data.  The problem is when another user is on the same record it does not show the lock indicator on the top left of the form for the second user.
So the second user thinks the record is not locked and starts to edit, when they move to the next record they get the write conflict error, that another user is editing the data to copy to clipboard or drop changes, Now the user knows it was being edited and drops changes, causing lost time that could have been avoided if the second user was able to see the locked indicator in the top left corner of the form.

So my question is why doesn't the locked indicator show up for the second user or is there a way to just pop a message box up that allows the second user to know that the record is being edited by another user.

Comment: I don't know about the downvote. But technically the row is NOT being edited. It was read from Access and displayed on a form that would allow editing. It is not currently in a modified state. If that were the case then you could keep a row locked indefinitely by simply reading it in Access. What you are asking for is not simple. This question has some great info on the topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596972/how-to-exclusively-lock-a-row-that-prevent-crud-operation

Comment: A little formatting and not yelling in an all-caps title goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

[Form.RecordLocks Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197407.aspx)

> The RecordLocks property only applies to forms, reports, or queries **in a Microsoft Access database**.

and

> Data in a form, report, or query from an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) database is treated as if the No Locks setting were chosen, regardless of the RecordLocks property setting.

It's also in the Online help.